# Webots R2019 OSM importer only generating trees

Tags: webots

The Webots R2019 OSM importer tool is only generating trees in the World (.wbt) files, as shown in this example:

```
python ~/webots/resources/osm_importer/importer.py --input=map.osm --output=map.wbt
 * OSM filed parsed
 * 0 roads generated
 * 0 crossroads generated
 * 0 buildings generated
 * 271 trees generated
 * 0 barriers generated
 * 0 rivers generated
 * 0 areas (forest, water, farmland, etc.) generated
 * 0 parking lines generated
 * map centered with this offset: 308595.591727,5153850.12847).
 * reference coordinates: 46.511,6.505.
 * projection used: '+proj=utm +north +zone=32 +lon_0=6.505000 +lat_0=46.511000 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'.
Done.
```

Does anyone know why the other object are not showing up? I tested the importer with the default latitude-longitude coordinates that comes in the Webots R2019.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the importer is not finding the configuration file and therefore doesn't know how to export all the missing objects.

To fix the problem, you should either:

- Launch the importer directly from the '~/webots/resources/osm_importer/' folder.
- Specify where is located the configuration file (e.g. 'python ~/webots/resources/osm_importer/importer.py --input=map.osm --output=map.wbt --config-file=~/webots/resources/osm_importer/config.ini')
- Apply the fix of https://github.com/omichel/webots/pull/146/files.